# Why is the bowling end changed every over in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Why is the bowling end changed regularly (i.e. after every over) in cricket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switching of batting and bowling ends after every over is done to make the game fair and reduce any advantage due to external factors such as:

- **Wind direction** (which might support the batsman or the bowler)
- **Ground dimensions** (the ground might have certain boundaries shorter or longer than the others)
- **Pitch conditions** (batting continuously on one side might degrade the pitch from that end; one side might have more spin or bounce than the other)

As an added bonus, it even helps improve the viewing angles of the crowd since both ends get to face the on-strike batsman every alternate over.

Comment: Yup, also light - it evens out the impact of the light as the sun starts to go down. Lots of reasons, really, which amount to "making the conditions even".

In ODIs, they even use two separate balls (since 2011) - one from each end.